# Git Error: fatal: bad object refs/heads/xxx. What happens when I delete?

Tags: git

When I commit to git, I have started getting this message:

```
warning: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause
and remove .git/gc.log
Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.

fatal: bad object refs/heads/master 2
fatal: failed to run repack
```

Drilling into the .git folder:

```
danieldonaldson@Daniels-Mac-mini wb2-web % cd .git
danieldonaldson@Daniels-Mac-mini .git % ls
COMMIT_EDITMSG          ORIG_HEAD               hooks                   info
COMMIT_EDITMSG 2        config                  index                   logs
FETCH_HEAD              description             index 2                 objects
HEAD                    description 2           index 3                 packed-refs
HEAD 2                  gc.log                  index 4                 refs
danieldonaldson@Daniels-Mac-mini .git % cd refs
danieldonaldson@Daniels-Mac-mini refs % cd heads
danieldonaldson@Daniels-Mac-mini heads % ls
master 2        webgame
```

I can see the I assume problematic file. I'm currently using branch webgame.

```
danieldonaldson@Daniels-Mac-mini heads % git branch
warning: ignoring ref with broken name refs/heads/master 2
  master
  tournamentmods
* webgame
danieldonaldson@Daniels-Mac-mini heads %
```

shows what I expected to see. If I remove the "master 2" head, will I be able to merge what I'm working on now into the master branch, since it shows up anyway? Or do I need to pull a new version? Would it be better to push what I'm working on to master and then grab a fresh version of everything from there?

Just trying to get a picture of what's actually about to happen.

Comment: I think something or you messed files in the repository folder and you should remove all the files ending with a space and a number (which should be copied of original good files). By security moved them in another backup folder. It should fix your errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`master 2` is not a valid ref name. The other files ending with  `2` are not natural Git internal files either. As `master 2` is a file, you can see its content.

```
cat "master 2"
```

In a normal `.git/refs/heads/foo` file, it should have a sha1value of a commit. From the error `fatal: bad object refs/heads/master 2`, I think the "master 2" contains something else. Even if it looks like a sha1value, it's not a valid one or there is no actual object. You can back up "master 2" and other files ending with  `2`, and then just remove them out of `.git/`. It does not affect `master`.

Besides, it's better to find out how these abnormal files are created and correct it.

Comment: I don't think that I'm going to discover that. That's the original branch, and it's never been changed, apart from the usual commits. So I'm at a loss. I'm going to remove it, and delete the log, and let's hope for the best. Weird.

Comment: In the end, blowing away the 'Master 2' file and the log, per the git messages did work. No clear indication how the problem arose, though...